# Taking minimum difference of dates between two data frame for the same id

Tags: r, dataframe, date, apply, plyr

my problem is simple. I have 2 data frame, each of them has a a column of dates (%Y-%m-%d),  and a column for the ids. One has just one id per row, the other one has multiple rows for the same id. I want to take the value so that it presents the minumum difference for the dates. Now I explain better with an example:

df1 (single values for colA):

```
+-------+------------+------+------+-------+-------+
| colA  |    colB    | colC | colD | colE  | colF  |
+-------+------------+------+------+-------+-------+
| 3000  | 2011-01-20 |    2 | 3.43 | 2.01  | 1.63  |
| 3001  | 2012-04-06 |    1 | 1.12 | -0.63 | -1.16 |
| 3002  | 2012-04-24 |    2 | 2.28 | -0.18 | -0.12 |
| 3003  | 2012-04-13 |    2 | 1.27 | -0.51 | -0.82 |
| 3004  | 2011-08-24 |    5 | 5.30 | 2.68  | 2.10  |
| 3006  | 2011-08-02 |    2 | 2.12 | -0.27 | -2.60 |
+-------+------------+------+------+-------+-------+
```

df2 (multiple values for first column (X)):

```
+------+---------------+----------+
| colX |     colY      | colZ     |
+------+---------------+----------+
| 3000 | 2011-02-01    |        0 |
| 3000 | 2012-03-01    |        0 |
| 3000 | 2013-02-01    |        0 |
| 3000 | 2014-03-01    |        1 |
| 3000 | 2015-03-01    |        0 |
| 3000 | 2016-04-01    |        0 |
| 3002 | 2011-03-01    |        1 |
| 3002 | 2011-08-01    |        1 |
| 3002 | 2012-04-01    |        0 |
+------+---------------+----------+
```

In this case I see the first value in colA (df1) and compute all the differences in months between 2011-01-20 with all of the dates for 3000 in df2 (2011-02-01, 2012-03-01,ecc), so the first 6 rows. I take only the minimum difference, so in this case is the first one (2011-02-01) that is almost one month. So at the end I should have df1 with 3 new columns (Y and Z and diff) so the minimum date on df2, 0/1 of Z and the difference of the 2 date in days.

e.g. for 3000 (for the difference I take the abs):

```
3000  2011-01-20  2  3.43  2.01  1.63  2011-02-01 0 12
```

What function should I use? apply? ddply?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (just be careful of how you define the date operations as this is not clear in your question):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Data
df1 <- structure(list(colA = c(3000L, 3001L, 3002L, 3003L, 3004L, 3006L
), colB = c("2011-01-20", "2012-04-06", "2012-04-24", "2012-04-13", 
"2011-08-24", "2011-08-02"), colC = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L), 
    colD = c(3.43, 1.12, 2.28, 1.27, 5.3, 2.12), colE = c(2.01, 
    -0.63, -0.18, -0.51, 2.68, -0.27), colF = c(1.63, -1.16, 
    -0.12, -0.82, 2.1, -2.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
df2 <- structure(list(colX = c(3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L), colY = c("2011-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2013-02-01", 
"2014-03-01", "2015-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-08-01", 
"2012-04-01"), colZ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

#Code
#Compute
dfo <- df2 %>% rename(colA=colX) %>% left_join(df1) %>% 
  mutate(Diff=abs(12*(year(as.Date(colB))-year(as.Date(colY)))+month(as.Date(colB))-month(as.Date(colY))),
         Diffdays=abs(as.Date(colB)-as.Date(colY))) %>% group_by(colA) %>%
  filter(Diff==min(Diff))
#Format
vars <- c(names(df1),names(df2)[-1],'Diff','Diffdays')
#Data
dfo %>% select(vars)

# A tibble: 2 x 10
# Groups:   colA [2]
   colA colB        colC  colD  colE  colF colY        colZ  Diff Diffdays
  <int> <chr>      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <int> <dbl> <drtn>  
1  3000 2011-01-20     2  3.43  2.01  1.63 2011-02-01     0     1 12 days 
2  3002 2012-04-24     2  2.28 -0.18 -0.12 2012-04-01     0     0 23 days
```

Please check if this fits to what you want.

Comment: Thanks it works, for the diff I referred just to the differences in terms of the days of distance between the 2 date. However I don't understand what is exactly means the variable Diff; it is the months right ?

Comment: @Will I added all details so that you understand clearly. Sorry if this was confusing. If you feel comfortable with this answer you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer :)

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks a lot. Only one point. I changed the filter part into: filter(Diffdays==min(Diffdays)), because in another dataset there are in the result duplicate rows, because they have the same number of months, but different number of days. In my advice using days gives less chance to have duplicates.

Comment: @Will As you mentioned you can do that or also you could consider using `filter(!duplicated(colA))` to remove duplicated rows. It is up to you.